# Вращение и масштабирование при наложении картинок

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при наложении картинок повернуть одну картинку относительно другой (желательно в градусах) и отмасштабировать?

Есть две картинки:

[image: map]
[image: res]

Сейчас для наложения использую код:

```
from PySide2 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QGuiApplication([])
# Положим одну картинку на другую
pixmap_map = QtGui.QPixmap('map.jpg')
painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap_map)
painter.begin(pixmap_map)
painter.setOpacity(0.5)
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, QtGui.QPixmap('res.jpg'))
painter.end()
pixmap_map.save('map_plus_res.jpg')
```

Получаю результат:

[image: res_map]

Как res.jpg сместить, повернуть и немного увеличить? Примерно так:

[image: Желаемое]

Answer (score 0):

```
from PySide2 import QtGui
 
 
app = QtGui.QGuiApplication([])
# Положим одну картинку на другую
pixmap_map = QtGui.QPixmap('map.jpg')
pixmap_zone = QtGui.QPixmap('res.jpg')
# **************************************
pixmap_zone = pixmap_zone.scaled(300, 300)
t = QtGui.QTransform().rotate(35)
# **************************************
painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap_map)
painter.begin(pixmap_map)
painter.setOpacity(0.5)
painter.drawPixmap(150, 150, pixmap_zone.transformed(t))
painter.end()
pixmap_map.save('map_plus_res.jpg')
```

[image: res]